# sed question: what does "s/ quiet init=.*$//" mean?

Tags: sed

I am having trouble understanding the command below. I understand the argument `-i` means 'insert' and the last argument obviously references the file to be altered but could someone explain the second argument - `s/ quiet init=.*$//`

```
sed -i 's/ quiet init=.*$//' /boot/cmdline.txt
```

The file `/boot/cmdline.txt` looks like this:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet  init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh
```

Comment: The effect of this command is to change the above text to: dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait

Answer (score 3):

`-i` for GNU's `sed` actually means to modify the file in-place, not "insert"

the rest is the sed script `s` means we're going to do a substitution, then the first `/` marks the start of the regex until the next `/` so in this case the pattern is `quiet init=.*$` which will find the string `quiet init=` and everything from there until the end of the line.  The next part is what to substitute for the matched expression, in our case it is an empty string, so we effectively delete that part of the line

Comment: Great answer - if I wanted to replace the string with another for example how would I do this?

Comment: You put the replacement string between the second and third `/` characters

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've confused sed command line options with sed commands themselves.

An option modifies the default behavior of `sed` and sed command(s) determines the manipulation that you wish to do with `sed`.

`-i` in your case is inplace edit which means make the changes permanently written to the file in question, so you're changing the file

Dont confuse this with the `i` command which is used to insert a line at a desired place. For example

```
sed -i '1,i\header' file # i inside single quotes is command
```

adds the line `header` to the first line of the file.

The `s` in your case is the substitution command, the general format for which is

`s/pattern/substition/flag`

See [[ sed manual ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for more details.